# Paypal donation page without registration

Tags: paypal

is there any way to let donors to pay without paypal registration?just by credit card. I have created donation page but it contains filed for paypal password

Comment: What country are you located in and are you using the PayPal donate button created from your account?

Answer (score 1):

As long as PayPal Account Optional setting is turned on in your PayPal account, the donate button will allow you to pay with guest checkout if the customer does not select it as a recurring donation.

The page looks different than your usual PayPal checkout, though, so it is easy to overlook.

Look for a section in the bottom left that says:
**Don't have a PayPal account?**
Use your credit card or bank account (where available)

Comment: ya but in the provided form for paying with a credit cart they ask for paypal password https://gyazo.com/ee09028f98387aaf4719b562bf50591a

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: the donation button displayed mandatory fields to create an account (email and password) at the end of the donation form.

After unsuccessfully searching in the settings and documentation for hours, I noticed by chance that the email address of my Paypal account was **not confirmed**.
After confirming it, the button form didn't ask for an account creation anymore.